# How to calculate $I(x)=\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}(t-x)}$ by Residue theorem [$|x|>1$]

Tags: residue-calculus

How to calculate $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}(t-x)}$ for $|x|>1$ by Residue theorem? I could do is just as:
$$I(x)=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta-x}\\
=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi}^\pi \frac{d\tau}{\sqrt{\frac{1-\cos \tau}{2}}-x}.$$

It is difficult to do now by replacing $z=e^{i\tau}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have done that last step - as you have already realised, it doesn't help.

Instead you should notice that
$$\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta-x}
  =\int_{\pi/2}^\pi \frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta-x}$$
- to prove this either think of the graph of the integrand, or substitute $\theta\gets\pi-\theta$.  Doing the same for the integral from $-\pi/2$ to $0$, your integral becomes
$$I(x)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \frac{d\theta}{\sin\theta-x}\ ,$$
and now you will find that the usual complex substitution works fine.

Comment: The integral in the RHS should have
$-\cos\left(\theta\right)$ instead of $\sin\left(\theta\right)$.

Comment: @FelixMarin, no it should not: $\sin(\pi-\theta)=\sin\theta$.

Comment: $\displaystyle{\large\int_{0}^{\pi/2}{{\rm d}\theta \over \sin\left(\theta\right) - x} =\int_{0 + \pi/2}^{\pi/2 + \pi/2}{{\rm d}\theta \over \sin\left(\theta - \pi/2\right) - x}=\int_{\pi/2}^{\pi}{{\rm d}\theta \over -\cos\left(\theta\right) - x}}$.

Comment: But you are substituting $\theta+\pi/2$ and I am not.  Your answer appears to be a possible alternative but mine is also correct.  Moreover, in yours the integrand has changed and therefore, as far as I can see, cannot easily be combined with the original integral.

Comment: You are right. Both results are equivalent. I used the one in my last comment to perform the calculation. Sorry. Thanks.

Comment: Not a problem!  I didn't actually complete the evaluation in my answer because I judged from the question that the OP is familiar with the $z=e^{i\theta}$ substitution.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you with a "raw" answer while I figure it out. http://symbolab.com/solver/step_by_step/%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D(%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-t%5E%7B2%7D%7D(t-x)%7D)dt%20

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{{\rm I}\pars{x} = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}{\dd\theta \over \sin\pars{\theta} - x}:
     \ {\large ?}\,,\qquad\verts{x} > 1}$

> \begin{align}
> {\rm I}\pars{x}&=\int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over -\cos\pars{\theta} - x}
> =\half\bracks{%
> \int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over -\cos\pars{\theta} - x}
> +
> \int_{0}^{\pi}{\dd\theta \over \cos\pars{\theta} - x}}
> \\[3mm]&=\half\int_{0}^{\pi}{-2x \over x^{2} - \cos^{2}\pars{\theta}}\,\dd\theta
> =-x\int_{0}^{\pi}{1 \over x^{2} - \bracks{1 + \cos\pars{2\theta}}/2}\,\dd\theta
> \\[3mm]&=-x\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\dd\theta \over 2x^{2} - 1 - \cos\pars{\theta}}
> =-x\int_{\verts{z} = 1}
> {\dd z/\pars{\ic z} \over 2x^{2} - 1 - \pars{z^{2} + 1}/\pars{2z}}
> \\[3mm]&=-2x\ic\int_{\verts{z} = 1}
> {\dd z \over z^{2} - 2\mu z + 1}\,,\qquad\qquad\mu \equiv 2x^{2} - 1 > 1
> \tag{1}
> \end{align}

The zeros of $z^{2} - 2\mu z + 1 = 0$  are given by:
\begin{align}
{\rm z_{-}}\pars{\mu} &= \mu - \root{\mu^{2} - 1}={1 \over \mu + \root{\mu^{2} - 1}}
< 1
\\
{\rm z_{+}}\pars{\mu} &= \mu + \root{\mu^{2} - 1} > 1
\end{align}

> By replacing these results in $\pars{1}$, we find:
>   \begin{align}
> \color{#00f}{\large{\rm I}\pars{x}}&=-2xi\pars{2\pi\ic}\,
> {1 \over 2{\rm z_{-}}\pars{\mu} - 2\mu}
> ={2\pi x \over -\root{\mu^{2} - 1}}
> =-\,{2\pi x \over \root{\pars{\mu - 1}\pars{\mu + 1}}}
> \\[3mm]&=-\,{2\pi x \over \root{\pars{2x^{2} - 2}\pars{2x^{2}}}}
> =\color{#00f}{\large -\,{\pi\sgn\pars{x} \over \root{x^{2} - 1}}}
> \end{align}